# Change datatype of entire database SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, type-conversion

I am trying to change the datatype to **decimal(30,10)** from **float**. The issue is i have a big database with more than 300 tables and they are all constrained with index and also joins.

Can anybody help me with the shortcut i can use to change the datatype in entire database?

I am using SQL Server Management studio 2012.

Comment: I don't think looking for shortcuts to changing the data type of numerous columns is the most advisable idea.

Comment: no shortcuts here. Just alot of painful work.

Comment: You could export out your table definitions as SQL 'CREATE TABLE'statements and unload your data, either as INSERT statements, or to a flat file. Then use a text editor to do a multiple changes on all the decimal(30,10) occurrences. Then recreate the database Then rebuild indexes from the SQL dump files, watching for any data errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the internal system tables that store the metadata about the tables and columns to generate your `ALTER TABLE` statements.

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ' + OBJECT_NAME(c.object_id) + ' ALTER COLUMN ' + c.name + ' DECIMAL(30,10);' AS sqlCommand
FROM sys.columns AS c
INNER JOIN sys.types AS t ON t.system_type_id=c.system_type_id
WHERE t.name='float';
```

This will return a result set that you can then paste back into a management studio query window and execute. Alternatively, you could automatically run the statements through [`sp_executesql`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) to run them as dynamic SQL but in these mass-update situations I usually like to inspect the statements I'm about to run.

**Do note:** This is not going to check if these statements are all going to SUCCEED. It will just generate the necessary DDL statements to modify the tables. If any of these columns are a primary or foreign key then it will fail. I'm sure there are a number of other situations where it may fail as well. After you run the automatically generated statements be sure to check all of the output messages to find out what actually happened.